# How to filter many2one res.parner field in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have

```
x_trainer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Trainer')
```

field, and I want to filter data in it by the value that is put in `category_id` tag field in `partner form`.

I want to show just those records in it their `category_id` tag value is defined Trainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand this correct, try to define you field in your view like:

```xml
<field name="x_trainer_id" domain="[('category_id','=',category_id[0][2])]" />
```

The field `category_id` has to be defined in that view, too. But if you extend the res.partner views, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: i have set tag as trainer and use this code .... ... <field name="x_trainer_id" domain="[('category_id.name','=','trainer']" />   ..... now this code id working well for me ..... thanks...

Comment: Oh well, i didn't know that you use a special named tag 'trainer'. So yes, your way should be the right one. Mine is more dynamic and means: Only partners with a tag used in the actual partner, can be a trainer of the actual partner.

Comment: please tell me about this Question...    i'll be very thankful to you..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618187/how-can-i-use-function-value-in-domain-filter