# how can i use function value in Domain filter

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am getting current login user id by following function

```
    def _get_user_name(self, cr, uid, *args):
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    user_value = user_obj.browse(cr, uid, uid)
    return user_value.id or False
```

and now i want to use its value in this field's Domain like ....

```
    x_trainer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Trainer',domain=[('user_id.id','=','get_user_name')])
```

How is it possible? I'll be very thankful....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it as below:

```
x_trainer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Trainer',domain=lambda self: [('id', '=', self.env.uid)])
```

pass **`domain=lambda self: [('id', '=', self.env.uid)]`**

Comment: I want to filter just those partners which salesperson is current login user therefore i am using user_id.id ..... please tell me who is it possible?

Comment: Thanks your code with user_id.id at the place of id is working well for me.

Comment: this query is very genuine, at the beginning i also used to ask such query.

Comment: you can do the same for this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598262/how-to-filter-many2one-res-parner-field-in-odoo/37618889#37618889

Comment: sir how can i use this domain for existing field? like i want to use it for partner_id in event registration...

Comment: inherit the model and re-declare the field with the domain ,